# if data exist in another table , do not insert again

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I tried insert data from table1 to table2 with some additional data(See attachment)

[image]

```
Insert into table2(F1,F2,F3,F4)
select( F1,F2,'DEL','IN')
```

My question :
In TABLE2, if data exist table2.f3='DEL' then do not insert the above mentioned syntax again.

Please suggest me with the syntax

Comment: Please could you clarify; do you mean "if any column value of the source table is equal to the matching column in the target table, then do not insert any new values" or do you mean "insert all non-matching column values into the target table"?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 and later has a useful `MERGE` command.

Comment: Thanks  it is working...

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2
   (
      F1,
      F2,
      F3,
      F4
   )
SELECT
      F1,
      F2,
      'DEL',
      'IN'
   FROM
      table1
   WHERE
      NOT EXISTS
         (
            SELECT
                  *
               FROM
                  table2
               WHERE
                  F1 = table1.F1
                  AND F2 = table1.F2
                  AND F3 = 'DEL'
         );
```